# How to pass flag from childform to parent?

Tags: c#

i have problem with passing boolean flag from childform to parentform.

I know how to pass it from parentform to childform for example:

On mainform:

```
Camera settings = new Camera(this.fullPath3);
settings.ShowDialog();
```

On childform:

```
public partial class Camera : Form
    {
        //Zmienne przekazywane - sciezka do zapisu wzorca, 
        string _fullPath3;
```

...

```
  public Camera(string fullPath3)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        _fullPath3 = fullPath3;
```

and it's working. How to add a bool Flag, as a return from my childform?

something like that:

On childform:

```
 public Camera(string fullPath3, bool flag)
```

On mainform:

```
  Camera settings = new Camera(this.fullPath3,this.flag);
  settings.ShowDialog();
  if (flag==true) text2.text="OK!";
```

Comment: Why not create an event on your child form and just hook onto that event on your parent form. You'll be able to pass information back to the parent form like this.

Comment: You can use event. [Heres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382750/adding-an-event-handler-for-a-control-in-child-form-from-parent-form-in-c/6382869#6382869) my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, `Camera` is a form so just add a public property to  it.

```
public class Camera : Form
{
   private string _fullPath3;
   private bool flag;
    public Camera(string fullPath3)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        _fullPath3 = fullPath3;
    }

    // set flag to something somewhere
    public bool Flag{ get{ return flag; } }

}
```

Now just:

```
Camera settings = new Camera(this.fullPath3);
settings.ShowDialog();
if (settings.Flag) text2.text="OK!";
```

remember that `ShowDialog` halts execution!

Comment: Camera settings = new Camera(this.fullPath3,this.flag) without "this.flag" is working -> Camera settings = new Camera(this.fullPath3) Tnx ;)

Comment: @Elfoc - yup, I copied your code and should have removed that from the ctor. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement an internal or public property in your `Camera` form, and set this property within it.

Something like this:

```
  Camera settings = new Camera(this.fullPath3,this.flag);
  settings.ShowDialog();
  if (settings.Flag) text2.text="OK!";
```