# Transfer Value from childform to Parentform c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass flag from childform to parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172448/how-to-pass-flag-from-childform-to-parent)

Can any body help me to send the values from childForm to parentForm. I have declared an int id variable in parentForm, now I want to send the textbox1.Text value from childForm to that int variable of parentForm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make id a public property and assign the value in child form.

**In parent form**

```
//Declare public property 
public string ID { get; set; }

//Create child form in some method.
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
form2.Show();
```

**In child form**

```
Form1 m_parent ;
public Form2(Form1 frm1)
{ 
     InitializeComponent(); 
     m_parent = frm1; 
}

m_parent.ID = textbox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Get Property in Child form and retrieve it in Parent form after closing child

Send a Reference variable to child form from Parent form