# Accessing Button properties from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I know this is a very common question, my problem is i have tried several methods and none of have worked for me.

What i have is two forms and what i need is for a button press on one form to set the enabled property of a button on my second form to true.

As i say i've tried multiple methods and none have worked so far.

Comment: you can do it with event. [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6382869/754438)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a button on second form PUBLIC(you can do that in *cs file or from control's "properties" window in VS) and add instance of second form to the first one. Or you can declare some [delegate](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/events.html) in second form, to change button properties, and invoke it in the first one.
Actually there are more variants, ive just mentioned 2 :)

Comment: The current method im trying involve both buttons being public and then in the button click code on my second form, i create an instance of my parent class  Main btnenable = new Main(); and the do this btnenable.btnaddlvl4.Enabled = true; but that didnt work.

Comment: @nexus490 , stop..by writing `Main btnenable = new Main();` you wont get INSTANCE of existing form..you create the new one(see the "new" keyword http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4(v=vs.71).aspx). If you want to do that this way - you probably should add the property to the child form of parent's type, like `Main Parent{get;set;}` and set it in parent form, when instantiating the child one: `Child child = new Child(); child.Parent = this;` . A bit messy, but hope this will help you to make your code working. @Reniuz provided better solution with events see his comment.

Comment: The answer Reniuz provided was confusing to me, i couldnt follow it. How would i do it then, instead of using new?

Comment: Just a moment, i'll provide you the code, to help. Hope i understood you properly.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?63a7c59kjet6hnd See 2 forms with enable disable button.

Comment: @nexus490 , glad to hear. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Let's call your forms **Form A** and **Form B**.

Does **Form A** contain an instance of **Form B**?  Does it call **FormB.Show()**?

If it does, you can create an event in **Form B**, and have **Form A** listen for it.

If it doesn't, you still create the event in **Form B**, but you have whatever called **Form B** listen for it, then pass the message on to **Form A**

Put this inside of **Form B**:

```
public delegate void ClickButton();
public event ClickButton ButtonWasClicked;
```

When the button is clicked, call ButtonWasClicked();

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonWasClicked();
}
```

Put this in **Form A**:

```
private FormB formB;

public FormA()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    formB = new FormB();
    formB.ButtonWasClicked += new FormB.ClickButton(formB_ButtonWasClicked);
}

void formB_ButtonWasClicked()
{
    label1.Text = "Button was clicked: " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Source:

http://darin.hoover.fm/code/dl/FormEvents.zip

Answer (score 1):

You should create a public method in you second form that enable the button, and add a reference to the second form in your first form. Then, on a OnClick event just call that method.

Here a sample code I create:

Class1.cs

```
class Class1
    {

            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            Form1 form1;

            public Class1()
            {
                //Application.Run(form1);
                //Application.Run(form2);
               form1 = new Form1(form2);
                form1.ShowDialog();

            }

    }
```

Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void enableB()
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 f2;
        public Form1(Form2 f)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            f2 = f;
            f2.Show();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            f2.enableB();
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This smells like homework.
You need to have the 2 forms know about eachother. Either by adding the instance to one form, or having a third object control both forms. You can register to the button click events more than once. (i.e you can have 5 forms listening to 1 forms button click and all 5 forms could react differently). This way you can have the button click affect its own form and the second form can also register to the event and set its own buttons enabled to true/false as required.
Example:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    MyOtherForm OtherForm;
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        OtherForm = new MyOtherForm();
        OtherForm.ButtonINeedToListenFor.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonINeedToListenFor_Click);
    }

    void ButtonINeedToListenFor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         this.MyDependingButton.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```