# accessing form controls from the class file

Tags: c#

I have one mdi form and many child forms all the child form contains panel control named as panel1 now i want to access panel1 control from my class file for that i write the following code but it is not working.
Class1.cs file :

```
public partial class FormBase : Form
{
    public FormBase()
    {
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.FormLoad);
        //this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.FormResize);//error
        this.panel1.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.FormResize);//error as a panel1 is not access
    }
    protected virtual void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }

    protected virtual void FormResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //error : panel1 control has a red underline
        panel1.Left = (this.ClientSize.Width - panel1.Width) / 2;//error as a panel1 is not access
        panel1.Top = (this.ClientSize.Height - panel1.Height) / 2;//error as a panel1 is not access
    }
}
```

now my one of the child form 
frmAddNewEmployee.cs

```
public partial class frmAddNewEmployee : FormBase
{
    public frmAddNewEmployee()
    {   InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void FormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.FormLoad(sender, e);
    }

    protected override void FormResize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.FormResize(((Panel)sender).Name, e);//error
        base.FormLoad(sender, e);//error
    }
}
```

so my question is how to access this panel1 control of the child forms from my Class1.cs file

Comment: It seems that `panel1` is private; open `FormBase`, select panel1 and change "Modifiers" property in Properties window from "Private" to "Protected"

Comment: I think you might benefit from this answer also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223387/accessing-button-properties-from-another-form

Comment: Thanks. I have tried and change i change modifier as Protected but yet error. Any other option you have so please give me.

Comment: Thanks you. but not solve please any other answer so give me.