# Calling function from different form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on a Rythm Game for for my course project, and I am having trouble implementing BGM on/off button.

Here is my simplified code:

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
    public SplashScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            string path= System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume = 0;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = path.Remove(path.Length - 44) + "\\assets\\main.wav";
        }
        
        
        void BGMoff()
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.mute = true;
        }
        void BGMon()
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.mute = false;
        }
        
        
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 main = new Form2();
            main.BGM_off += BGMoff;
            main.BGM_on += BGMon;
        }
    }
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
        
    {
        public delegate void ClickButton();
        public event ClickButton BGM_off;
        public event ClickButton BGM_on;
        
        bool BGM = true
        
        public void button4_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (BGM)
            {
                button4.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.BGMoff;
                BGM = false;
                BGM_off?.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                button4.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.BGMon;
                BGM = true;
                BGM_on?.Invoke();


            }
        }
    }
```

This was made based on comment from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10223387/accessing-button-properties-from-another-form) by Darin. I believe I followed the steps correctly to get access to `axWindowsMediaPlayer`, but I was wrong.

Comment: In order to call a method from `Form1` in `Form2`, you need `Form2` to have access to the  instance of `Form1`. However in your case `BGM_on` is actually an event of `Form2`, so you can invoke it simply by `BGM_on();` (assuming it is not `null`).

Comment: It was NULL, so i used invoke. i tried other way to make Events not NULL but result is still the same.

Comment: If an event like `BGM_on` is `null`, it means that nobody registered to it (with `+= <event handler>`).

Comment: I just changed main.BGM_off += BGMoff;       to      main.BGM_off +=new Form2.ClickButton( BGMoff); and it is still giving me null on events so, i assume im still missing somthing i guess.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After frustraiting hours of experementation with code i realized my mistake.

It was in a part of code i didnt even include as it was somewhat unrelated to event handling itself.

`main.Show(this);` is the culprid. It's code used to open new form, aka switch between menues. I was creating new object `form2` of Form2 and going there instead of the one where we signed up for events, therefore events were returning null. and failing to execute functions.

Comment: That is what I meant when I suggested in my answer to make it a member. This would mean the same instance you registered your events with, will be actually displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily call the function of another form by creating and saving the second form in a variable and call the function from it.

Comment: If  you mean somthing like this:
`form1 xyz = new form1 
xyz.dostuff();`
unfortunatly that doesnt work, for some reason as i tested it on a new expty project.

Comment: Its impossible due to the fact that MediaPlayer's are non static object therefore cannot be used in static methos to be used outside their class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your issue is that in this line in `Form1_Load`:

```
Form2 main = new Form2();
```

`main` is created as a local variable.
After you allocate it and register to the events, it goes out of scope.

You can make it a member variable of `Form1` instead:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // ...
    Form2 main;
    // ...
}
```

This way the lifetime of `main` will be related to the lifetime of your `Form1`.
You code in `Form1_Load` should be:

```
main = new Form2();       // NOTE: this is the member this.main
main.BGM_off += BGMoff;
main.BGM_on += BGMon;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, unfortunatly event is still going NULL.