# Accessing other forms value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 2 forms namely, Form1 & Form2.

In Form1 I have a String named "HumanName", this "HumanName" has a value which is from a textbox.text. Also i have button named Button1.

In Form2 I has a label named Label1.

This is what I want to accomplish.
When I hit/press Button1, the `Label1.Text=HumanName`

Form1:

```
HumanName = textbox.text, Button1
```

Form2:

```
Label1.Text = HumanName
```

here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void PersonalInformationToForm2()
    {
        HumanName = textBox_Name.Text;
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        PersonalInformationToForm2();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Label1.Text=HumanName;   //I need the value of HumanName from Form1        
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can find the form you have open and access its properties/methods as needed.

Comment: Perhaps overkill for your scenario, but in general you could bind the controls to the same source, which contains a property HumanName(with a HumanNameChanged event). Then all bound controls would update their display when the property is changed (even if there are more instances of form1 and form2)

Comment: I think [it's][1] what you search. ;)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382750/adding-an-event-handler-for-a-control-in-child-form-from-parent-form-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Form1 encapsulate the control in a Property

```
public string GetTextboxText {get{ return Textbox1.Text;}}
```

On the other form

```
var formOne = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
Label1.Text = formOne.GetTextboxText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor for Form2 which takes the HumanName.

Then upon button press in Form1, create a new instance of the form and pass in Textbox1.Text

Answer (score 0):

in Form2 create a constructor in the following way

```
public void Form2(string name)
{
  Label1.Text=name;
}
```

Noe from Form1 we can send the value in the following way

```
string HumanName=textbox.text;
Form2 frm2=new Form2(HumanName);
frm2.Show();
```

Comment: That isn't a constructor, you should overload the constructor like: `public Form2(string name){ Label1.Text = name;}`

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance for Form1 which is accessible for Form2 you can do it like this:

```
public static Form2 Instance;

public Form2()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     Instance = this;
}
```

Set the modifier for Label1 to true in the properties.

When hitting that button1 on Form1 do this:

```
private void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Form2.Instance.Label1.Text = textBox1.Text;
}
```