# Inheriting Button in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a FormBase class which acts as the base for other forms which handles stuff like FormClosing and FormLoad. I have a ButtonReturn in each form which inherits from the FormBase. Is there any way to move the function of this button to FormBase?

Instead of this in each form:

```cs
    private void ButtonPowrot_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dialog = false;
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
```

I would like to keep it only in the FormBase. But I don't know how to set the _Click action in designer to make this work. How can I make this work?

Comment: I dont see the problem. Just put the button on `FormBase` and doubleclick it so you can write this code on your `FormBase`. It will appear on every inherited form and will just work

Comment: And after that, remove the one you already made on every inherited form off course

Comment: @GuidoG What if the forms have different sizes and different locations for the button?

Comment: on your inherited forms, you can position the button where you want, and chance it size. It will show up in the designer, you can do with the button what you want, only you cannot delete it because it is owned by the base form

Comment: you will have to set the `modifier` property of the button to `protected` on `FormBase` to be able to change position and size and other properties on the inherited forms

Comment: It works, but doesn't show up in the designer, so I can't position it in the right spot.

Comment: it shows up in the designer when I do this here.

Comment: check the position using the debugger at runtime, maybe it is place outside the visual area of the form somehow

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio and rebuilding the solution helped. Now I can see the buttons in designer. Thank you

Comment: If you want to allow only specific layouts in the derived Forms, you can override `OnLayout` in the base Form. If you specify, for example, a relative `Location` for a Control, in the derived Forms you will be allowed to set a different `Size`, but not a different `Location`. If you try to move the Control, it will be reset to the original position. But the size can be set to anything else. Of course, as GuidoG mentioned, the Modifiers property must ne set to `Protected` or `Protected Internal`, so the member variable will be generated locally.

Answer (score 0):

If each child form has the same button why you don't add it one time just in parent form to be available for all children?

Btw, your solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382750/adding-an-event-handler-for-a-control-in-child-form-from-parent-form-in-c-sharp).

Comment: What I wanted to do is avoid repeating the same code in each child form, and the solution in the link would only change the repeated code into another repeated code. @GuidoG in a comment gave me the solution and explained what was wrong in my approach.