# How to change textbox value when I change it from another window

Tags: c#, wpf

Ok, I have two windows in my WPF app. I want to change the text of a textbox, from a second window. This should also happen parallel.

I know, this is about multithreadin, but I know very little about it.

This is what my current code looks like, but this is for copying textbox text.

```
private void copyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    secondWindow = new SecondWindow();
    secondWindow.textBoxS.Text = textBox.Text;
    secondWindow.Show();
}
```

But, I want to change textbox texts dynamically between the MainWindow and the Second window.
So I tried something like this:

```
 private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
      Task t = Task.Run(() =>
      {
          secondWindow = new SecondWindow();
          secondWindow.textBoxS.Text = textBox.Text;
          secondWindow.Show();
      });
      t.Start();
 }
```

Comment: No, it's not about multithreading. Having two windows doesn't mean you have two threads. In fact, both your windows should run on the same UI thread. Please describe your use case with more detail.

Comment: You dont want to make a new window every time the text changes, you need the handle of the other window..

Comment: [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382750/adding-an-event-handler-for-a-control-in-child-form-from-parent-form-in-c-sharp/6382869#6382869). It's for winforms but idea is the same - use event

Comment: You'd do well to look into MVVM so that you have a common view model that both windows use so when you change the text in one window, the changes are handled in the other without having to write any special code.

Comment: When I write in mainwindow, I want it to change in the second window in real time. My English is bad. Maybe that's why I can't explain you.

Comment: @Nasirli01 check my answer

Comment: I agree with Fabulous. You should share a common viewmodel implements inotifypropertychanged and bind both textboxes text to a property in that. Learn MVVM. If this is totally impractical you could alternatively use a decoupled approach with a mediator or event aggregator. EG  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26070.communicating-between-classes.aspx

Comment: Pay careful attention to notes reminding you that creating a new window object isn't useful. You have to use the existing one. The marked duplicate offers a "quick and dirty" approach. Not ideal but it works. I have a theory: one reason it's hard to find existing questions that provide good MVVM-based answers is that when someone is using MVVM, this type of scenario "just works". People only have to ask questions about how  to do this when they are doing it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. I put two way in below:

**Method 1**

You can create a public method (e.g. SetTextBoxValue) and
pass the window that contains the TextBox to other window. Then change the TextBox value using that method. like this:

**MainWindow**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void SetTextBoxValue(string value)
    {
        SampleTextBox.Text = value;
    }

    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var otherWindow = new AnotherWindow(this);
        otherWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

**Other Window**

```cs
public partial class AnotherWindow
{
    private readonly MainWindow _mainWindow;

    public AnotherWindow(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        _mainWindow = mainWindow;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _mainWindow.SetTextBoxValue("New value from other window");
    }
}
```

---

**Method 2**

You can create a event for other window and subscribe to it in main window. like this:

**MainWindow**

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var otherWindow = new AnotherWindow();
        otherWindow.TextBoxValueChanged += OtherWindowOnTextBoxValueChanged;
        otherWindow.Show();
    }

    private void OtherWindowOnTextBoxValueChanged(object sender, TextBoxValueEventArgs e)
    {
        SampleTextBox.Text = e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

**Other Window**

```
public partial class AnotherWindow
{
    public event EventHandler<TextBoxValueEventArgs> TextBoxValueChanged;
    public AnotherWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var newValue = "New value from other window";
        OnTextBoxValueChanged(new TextBoxValueEventArgs(newValue));
    }

    protected virtual void OnTextBoxValueChanged(TextBoxValueEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxValueChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}

public class TextBoxValueEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string NewValue { get; set; }

    public TextBoxValueEventArgs(string newValue)
    {
        NewValue = newValue;
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this, initialize the second window in first window constructor

```
private SecondWindow _secondWindow;

public FirstWindow()
{
     _secondWindow = new SecondWindow();
}
```

and your second form before constructor

```
private string text;
public string Text
{
    get
    {
        return text;
    }
    set
    {
        textBoxOfSecondWindow.Text = value;
        text = value;
    }
}
```

then in the `copybutton` function

```
private void copyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _secondWindow.Text= textBox.Text;
    _secondWindow.Show();
}
```

in the `textchange` of the first window

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
      _secondwindow.Text = textBox.Text;
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your second window, place this code in the `textBox_TextChanged` method.

```
((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).txtFirstWindow.Text = txtSecondWindow.Text;
```

[image]

Comment: Controls are (rightly) private members. You can't just change a value on a control in some other window. Unless you make the control public. But that's a bad idea.

Comment: That is correct, thanks